# Node.js + socket.io + mongo with authorization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, cookies, socket.io

On my website users need to login with database account. My question is, how to auth socket.io only if database login pass and create my variable in cookie ?

Express with auth function from here [socket.io Auth](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing) works with sessionID, maybe i can prevent to give sessionID to moment when user log in to database ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [authorization function](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#global-authorization):

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
  // findDatabyip is an async example function
  findDatabyIP(handshakeData.address.address, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    if (data.authorized) {
      handshakeData.foo = 'bar';
      for(var prop in data) handshakeData[prop] = data[prop];
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(null, false);
    }
  }) 
});
```

- Replace findDatabyIP with your database lookup.
- Any attributes you set on handshakeData should be available in your "connection" handler via socket.handshake.sessionID.
- Call callback when you're done, with an error message (if applicable), and true if the connection is authorized, false if it's not.
- Parsing and reading the session's cookie may be difficult. [This discussion (especially jugglinmike's post)](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/588) may help.